# Redirect diary to other directory

Tags: diary

The Emacs diary is configured in `~/diary` as the default.

I want separate the configuration and my personal notes.

How could redirect the system's diary to other directory?

Comment: The default location for the `diary-file` (which variable is defined in `calendar.el`) is `~/.emacs.d/diary`.  Please elaborate regarding what you mean by the sentence:  "*The Emacs diary is configured in `~/diary` as the default.*"  Is it a *file* you are talking about?  Is it a *directory* you are talking about?  What is the purpose of the file/directory to which you refer?

Comment: ty, I am finding `diary-file` @lawlist

Comment: To change the location of the `diary-file`, you can use `(setq diary-file "/path/to/my/diary")` where `/path/to/my/diary` is an absolute path to the `diary` file on your hard drive.  If the file is in your HOME directory or a subdirectory of the HOME directory, you can use the `~` character to abbreviate the path to the HOME directory.